# When is an elliptic curve of $j$-invariant $j=0,1728$ supersingular over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $p$ be a prime, $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $j$-invariant is 0 or 1728.

Now I want to know if there is a criterion of when $E$ is supersingular.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_elliptic_curve),there is a table for small $p$, but I don't know the regularity of connection of $p$ and supersingular.

Comment: The $j$-invariants $0$ and $1728$ correspond to elliptic curves with CM by $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ and $\mathbb Z[i]$ respectively so their reduction mod $p$ will be supersingular precisely at primes $p$ that are split in the respective rings. In this case $p\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. 
My favorite way to see this is that the two pieces of the newton polygon are either preserved or flipped by the Galois action in the ordinary and supersingular case respectively.

Comment: Did you mean inva**r**iant?

Comment: If $(p)$ is inert in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ consider the reduction of $E:y^2=x^3+x$ modulo $p$ and $[i](x,y)=(-x,iy)$, then the Frobenius $\phi_p(x,y)=(x^p,y^p)$ doesn't commute with $[i] \in End(E\bmod p)$, this implies that $(E\bmod p)[p^\infty]$ can't be infinite so $E\bmod p$ is supersingular.

Comment: Conversely if $(p)$ splits in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ then $\phi_p$ commutes with $[i]$ so $\phi_p\in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ whence it can't be that $[p]=\phi_p^2 u$ for some $u\in Aut(E\bmod p)$ and $E\bmod p$ is ordinary.